# material-ui/reactjs menu component style is broken

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[image]

I followed the doc from below. 
http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/popover

```
<Popover
  open={this.state.open}
  anchorEl={this.state.anchorEl}
  anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'bottom'}}
  targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'top'}}
  onRequestClose={this.handleRequestClose}
>
  <Menu>
    <MenuItem primaryText="Sign out" onClick={this.props.logout} />
  </Menu>
</Popover>
```

Signout menu botton is ugly. Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `<MenuItem>` components renders a span with `type="button"` attribute, but in last versions of [materialize-css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/4.1.1/normalize.min.css) there is set a rule:

```
[type=reset], [type=submit], button, html [type=button] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
}
```

You can fix it by setting:

```
[type=button]{
  -webkit-appearance: none
}
```

In a global css file.

Comment: In React Material UI, components have inline style, so don't forget `!important` in the css file.

Comment: Actually, I didn't see that property to be overridden by inline styles. But it may be.

Comment: does this mean I need materialize css/js to be imported when I use MaterialUI? I tried to add it but it broke all the structure... guess it conflict with other css files.

Comment: Those styles are imported by default, all you have to do, is to override this rule in your own global css file.

Comment: Note that the descriptor will need to be *at least as specific* as the one in normalize.css, which is `html [type=button]`.  I used exactly that in my css file, which works because I have my styles *after* normalize in my html.  If your styles are first, you'll need to be more specific still.